# way to estimate time complexity which is based on step count

Tags: time-complexity

I want to ask a question about time complexity.

```
Sum (array,n)
{
1.1 total_sum = 0;
1.2 for (i=0;i<n;i++)
1.2.1 total_sum = total_sum +array[i];
1.3 return total_sum;
}
```

the total steps for 1.2 statement is 2(n+1)..
could anyone tell me that why it is 2(n+1) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say, i=n-1. It gets incremented, and the loop returns; one more comparison is made, this time it evaluates to false (because i is now equal to n). All in all, you run this 0, 1, ... ,n times, each time doing two operations -- together 2(n+1). Note that the i++ statement is evaluated only n times, but you have one extra statement at the beginning of the loop (i=0).

Comment: why is 2(n+1) but not n+1 only?

Comment: because you do (i) comparison and (ii) increment.

Comment: mean it increment once is n+1, and it compares i<n once also is n+1..therefore total is 2(n+1)... is that correct?

Comment: yes. Except that the increment is done n, not n+1, so it makes n + 1 + n, but then there is this first operation, i= 0, which makes it n + 1 + n + 1 = 2(n+1)

Comment: how about for (i=2;i<n;i++) ? it is 2(n-1)...why it is 2(n-1)? but not 2(n+1)

Comment: do that: let n=5 and run the loop manually, writing out every step. Then count the steps.